# How can I manipulate and display SVG graphics on Android?

Tags: android, image, graphics, svg

I would like to draw technical illustrations in my Android app.
I have images with shapes, and I have to change the size of those shapes based on input data. Thought that I could save those images as SVG, then I could manipulate the size of the shapes in it. For example, I would like to take a  with a specified ID, and change its width/height.

There're great SVG display libraries for Android, but I haven't found one which can also manipulate the graphics.

Do you know any library which can do this?

If not, how else should I draw my illustrations?